# Differential tetrahedron, area of slanted face?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, continuum-mechanics

[image]

The above diagram shows a cuboid containing a tetrahedron OABC.
When the cuboid represents a differential volume element all sides are small in size.

With the length of line $OA$ denoted by $|OA|$ and similarly for other lines, when we are dealing with a differential volume element

\begin{align}
|OA|&=\delta x   \nonumber \\
|OB|&=\delta y   \nonumber \\
|OC|&=\delta z   \nonumber 
\end{align}

and OABC is called a differential tetrahedron.

In the general case ( sides of any sizes ) let

\begin{align}
|OA|&=a   \nonumber \\
|OB|&=b   \nonumber \\
|OC|&=c   \nonumber 
\end{align}

What is the area, denoted by $A^{\prime}$, of the triangle $ABC$ in terms of $a,b,c$?

**Other Info.**

This type of triangle is important in elasticity and fluid mechanics and  probably elsewhere. 
Let

\begin{align}
u&=|AB|&=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}   \nonumber  \\
v&=|AC|&=\sqrt {a^2+c^2}   \nonumber \\
w&=|BC|&=\sqrt {b^2+c^2}   \nonumber \\
s&=\frac{1}{2}(u+v+w)   \nonumber \\
A^{\prime}&=\sqrt{ s(s-u)(s-v)(s-w)}   \nonumber 
\end{align}
So what is $A^{\prime}$ in terms of $a,b,c$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The material is important for physicists. It is important in fluid mechanics and elasticity.

Comment: @Qmechanic looks like you are correct, I have just been checking in the Help Centre about what questions I should ask here.

Answer (score 3):

One useful formula is the area of a triangle defined by vectors: $$A=|(\mathbf{v}_1 \times \mathbf{v}_2)/2|.$$ In your case you need to select a corner and use the differences: $$A=|(OB-OA)\times(OC-OA)/2|.$$

Assuming the parallelepiped has orthogonal edges, we can of course write out the vectors explicitly: $OA=(a,0,0), OB=(0,b,0), OC=(0,0,c)$ and the formula becomes $A=|(-a,b,0)\times(-a,0,c)/2|=|(bc,ac,ba)|/2=\sqrt{b^2c^2+a^2c^2+b^2a^2}/2.$

Comment: I used OB because the initial question used that slightly awkward notation. I prefer to give answers that tie in with the question-as-asked and then move towards a conclusion that is more general.

Comment: We have here an example  of the power of vector methods in algebraic geometry. Imagine trying to find the expression for the area, denoted by $A^{\prime}$, in terms of $a,b,c$, when it is originally given as $A^{\prime}=\sqrt{ s(s-u)(s-v)(s-w)}$, see the question, in 'Other Info'.

Comment: For a differential element of volume in Cartesian coordinates, where $a=\delta x, b=\delta y, c=\delta z$ the slanted face of the differential tetrahedron has area $A^{\prime}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\delta y^2 \delta z^2+\delta x^2 \delta z^2+\delta y^2\delta x^2}.$